# Problems with Eigen Tensor: Conflicting declaration

Tags: c++, eigen, tensor

I just tried to test the Eigen Tensor module in CodeBlocks 16.01 with GCC 4.9. As suggested by http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Tensor_support I added -std=c++0x, -std=c++11 or -std=c++1y as compiler flags but I can't make it work. Already

```
#include <unsupported/Eigen/CXX11/Tensor>
```

yields error message depending on the flags I use. In case of -std=c++0x or -std=c++11

```
||=== Build: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\Tensor|52|error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\stdint.h|31|note: previous declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\Tensor|53|error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uint32_t'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\stdint.h|32|note: previous declaration as 'typedef unsigned int uint32_t'|
||=== Build failed: 2 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

and in the case of -std=c++1y I get additional error messages:

```
||=== Build: Debug in Test (compiler: GNU GCC Compiler) ===|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\util\IntegralConstant.h|187|error: template declaration of 'const Eigen::internal::FixedInt<N> Eigen::fix'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\util\IndexedViewHelper.h|63|error: 'fix' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\util\IndexedViewHelper.h|63|error: expected primary-expression before ')' token|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h|142|error: 'fix' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h|142|error: 'fix' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h|142|error: expected primary-expression before ')' token|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h||In member function 'decltype (Eigen::seqN((((const Eigen::ArithmeticSequence<FirstType, SizeType, IncrType>*)this)->Eigen::ArithmeticSequence<FirstType, SizeType, IncrType>::m_first + ((((((const Eigen::ArithmeticSequence<FirstType, SizeType, IncrType>*)this)->Eigen::ArithmeticSequence<FirstType, SizeType, IncrType>::m_size + <expression error>) < (-1)) > <expression error>) * ((const Eigen::ArithmeticSequence<FirstType, SizeType, IncrType>*)this)->Eigen::ArithmeticSequence<FirstType, SizeType, IncrType>::|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h|143|error: 'fix' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h|143|error: expected primary-expression before ')' token|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h|207|error: 'fix' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h|207|error: 'fix' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h|207|error: expected primary-expression before ')' token|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h||In function 'decltype (Eigen::seqN((typename Eigen::internal::cleanup_index_type<FirstType>::type)(f), (((((typename Eigen::internal::cleanup_index_type<SizeType>::type)(l) - (typename Eigen::internal::cleanup_index_type<FirstType>::type)(f)) + <expression error>) < 1) > <expression error>))) Eigen::seq(FirstType, LastType)':|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h|211|error: 'fix' was not declared in this scope|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\..\..\..\Eigen\src\Core\ArithmeticSequence.h|211|error: expected primary-expression before ')' token|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\Tensor|52|error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long int int32_t'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\stdint.h|31|note: previous declaration as 'typedef int int32_t'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\eigen-eigen-c2947c341c68\unsupported\Eigen\CXX11\Tensor|53|error: conflicting declaration 'typedef long unsigned int uint32_t'|
C:\Program Files (x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\include\stdint.h|32|note: previous declaration as 'typedef unsigned int uint32_t'|
||=== Build failed: 15 error(s), 0 warning(s) (0 minute(s), 1 second(s)) ===|
```

Any ideas on what I did wrong or how to fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please clarify what the actuall question is? Is the question about why you have to add the compiler flags? If so I'd sugest that you make it a bit clearer.

Comment: Thanks first of all for your fast reply. I am sorry, I just notice my post was ambiguous and misleading, I corrected it now. It is not working for me even with the compiler flags that is what I intended to say! Any ideas what the issue might be? I have no clue if it is my own incompetence, the compiler, CodeBlocks or anything platform related.

Comment: Hey there, thanks for your answer as well. Sorry for having been imprecise again. I tried -std=c++0x, -std=c++1 and -std=c++1y separately. The error message you read above was for either of the first two cases, I added the error message for -std=c++1y (which is basically the same as for the aforementioned two plus some additional errors) as well now.
The flags in CodeBlocks can simply be set by clicking on them (Compiler flags/general) so I simply did that. I got CodeBlocks 16.01 with GCC 4.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's probably because your compiler doest not support [variable template](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B14#Variable_templates).
Variable template is supported since gcc 5.

https://www.gnu.org/software/gcc/projects/cxx-status.html

You can either upgrade compiler or modify eigen source code.